# bootstrap full year calendar setup

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to get this package http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com up and running. I've got nodeJS installed, have grabbed the package with npm and have setup an html page as per the usage instructions, but I cannot actually get the calendar to render. This is my first foray into nodejs, so I suspect I'm missing something straightforward. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Thanks as always. My html/js currently looks like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script src="./jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="./bootstrap-year-calendar/js/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.calendar').calendar()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And that element with the class `calendar`, that you are trying to select with `$('.calendar')`, is located where exactly …?

Comment: in bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js? i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Do you know what `$('.calendar')` does?

Comment: no, i actually have no idea.

Comment: Well it is supposed to select element(s) with the class `calendar`, to apply the functionality of this plugin _to_ ... only your document lacks any of those.

Comment: so is this effectively just designed to style/add js to an existing html calendar class?

Comment: No ... but it has to know _where_ on your page you want the calendar to appear ... and therefor you initialize it on an existing, empty container element, so that the plugin can render its calendar _into_ that element. (Or you might even want more than one calendar on a page.)